# kube helm charts - multiple values files

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

it might be simple question but can't find anywhere if it's duable;

Is it possible to have values files for helm charts (stable/jenkins let's say) and have two different values files for it?

I would like in values_a.yaml have some values like these:

```
master:
  componentName: "jenkins-master"
  image: "jenkins/jenkins"
  tag: "lts"
...
  password: {{ .Values.secrets.masterPassword }}
```

and in the values_b.yaml - which will be encrypted with AWS KMS

```
secrets:
  masterPassword: xxx
```

the above code doesn't work and wanted to know, as you can put those vars in kube manifests like it

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.config.name }}
  namespace: {{ .Values.config.namespace }}
...
```

can they be somehow passed to other values files

---

EDIT:

If it was possible I would just put the

```
master:
  password: xxx
```

in values_b.yaml but vars cannot be duplicated, and the official helm chart expects the `master.password` val from that file - so has to somehow pass it there but in encrypted way

Answer (score 4):

I'm not quite sure but this feature of `helm` might help you.

> Helm gives you the functionality to pass custom `Values.yaml` which have higher precedence over the fields of the main `Values.yaml` while performing `helm install` or `helm upgrade`.

#### For Helm 3

```sh
$ helm install <name> ./mychart -f myValues.yaml
```

#### For Helm 2

```sh
$ helm install --name <name> ./mychart --values myValues.yaml
```

Comment: hmmm not really helps as I already use it `helm3 upgrade --install jenkins stable/jenkins -f jenkins.yaml` and the values are not in typical yaml file but inside custom yaml teplated inside the yaml eg. `   configScripts:
      welcome-message: | (here is new line and my password config'`

Comment: @potatopotato, why don't you create a k8s secret for the password? and refer the secret name from your Values.yaml. You won't need an extra Values.yaml for that. And providing credentials via Values.yaml file isn't a good practice.

Comment: well even the secrets have to be stored somewhere, my computer or some git repo and to push it there it's good to encrypt it somehow - aws kms is a good way to do that

Comment: You can use multiple `-f` or `--values` options: `helm install ... -f values_a.yaml -f values_b.yaml`.  But you can't use templating in any Helm values file unless the chart specifically supports it (using the `tpl` function).

Answer (score 3):

The valid answer is from David Maze in the comments of the response of Kamol Hasan.

> You can use multiple -f or --values options: helm install ... -f
> values_a.yaml -f values_b.yaml. But you can't use templating in any
> Helm values file unless the chart specifically supports it (using the
> tpl function).

If you use multiple `-f` then latest value files override earlier ones.